# service not as advertised

Tags: systemd, sysv

I am trying to add a new sysV service on an Ubuntu 18.04 host. However the `service` command [does not behave as described in the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/service.8.html) - despite the presence of a file in /etc/init.d, "service" complains there is no systemd service file:

```
root@example.com:/etc/init.d# ls -l /etc/init.d/my-test-app
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 16 10:58 /etc/init.d/my-test-app -> /var/services/my-test.jar
root@example.com:/etc/init.d#
root@example.com:/etc/init.d#
root@example.com:/etc/init.d# service my-test-app status
Unit my-test-app.service could not be found.
root@example.com:/etc/init.d#
root@example.com:/etc/init.d#
root@example.com:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/my-test-app status
Running [9519]
root@example.com:/etc/init.d#
```

Is it because I am using a symlink? Something else?

Comment: AFAIK the backward compatibility between systemd and SysV relies on `systemd-sysv-generator`, which might not get invoked outside of a full restart (although you could see if `systemctl daemon-reload` is sufficient) - see for example [How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver: thanks, yes, running `systemctl daemon reload` sort of resolved the issue. But it things it is Inactive while the initscript reports it is running - but I get this with packaged sysV inits too. I'm really learning to hate systemd. If you repost as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backward compatibility between `systemd` and the SysV init system relies on hooks provided by `systemd-sysv-generator`, as descibed here:

- [How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts/233581#233581)

Generators should be run automatically on boot, however if you want to avoid rebooting it appears to be possible to run them on demand by invoking

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

From `man systemctl`:

> ```
>    daemon-reload
>        Reload the systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all
>        generators (see systemd.generator(7)), reload all unit files, and
>        recreate the entire dependency tree. While the daemon is being
>        reloaded, all sockets systemd listens on behalf of user
>        configuration will stay accessible.
> ```